# Create.js CPU High load

Tags: 2d, javascript, html-canvas, easeljs

I'm new in Create.js and I'm trying to make countdown progress bar.

I have this simple code:

```
var stage = new createjs.Stage("timerCanvas");

stage.canvas.width = document.getElementById('timerProgress').offsetWidth;
stage.canvas.height = document.getElementById('timerProgress').offsetHeight;

var square = new createjs.Shape();
square.graphics.beginFill('red').drawRect(0, 0, stage.canvas.width, stage.canvas.height);


stage.addChild(square);


createjs.Tween.get(square, { loop: false }).to({ scaleX: 0 }, 90000);

createjs.Ticker.timingMode = createjs.Ticker.RAF;
createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", stage);
```

My canvas width is 1920px and height 5px.
My CPU average load is 20%, when this script runs...

I think it is high load, for such simple script. Am I right?
If I am, What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I feel like this would be better suited to StackOverflow, but I don't know enough about Create.js to say if a game dev would know more about it.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with create.js, if I wanted to create a loading bar I would use regular JS, with a canvas or CSS and html. You may want to use:

```
lC=document.getElementById("load");
lCC=lC.getContext("2d");
lCBackground="rgba(0,0,0,0)";
lCForeground="red";
function load(a){
    lCC.fillStyle=lCForeground;
    lCC.fillRect(0,0,lC.width*a,lC.height);
    lCC.fillStyle=lCBackground;
    lCC.fillRect(lC.width*a,0,lC.width-lC.width*a,lC.height);
}
```

With

```
<canvas id="load" width="1920" height="5"></canvas>
```

Just call load with the percentage as a decimal (.50=50%)

You can use any [CSS Color](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value)

To un-render the loading bar use:

```
lCC.clearRect(0,0,lC.width,lC.height);
```

And will rerender when you call load again.

*Note: you can change the color of the loading bar at anytime during the program, and this supports stuff like [gradients](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasGradient) and [images](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasPattern)*

Answer (score 0):

Try using this. It draw a bar, fill it up, and then drain it. (You will probably have to change some things so that it works with easeljs):

```js
/* Get the canvas element */
 var c = document.getElementById('canvas');

/* Get the canvas' context */
 var ctx = c.getContext('2d');

/* Variables used for bar fill */
 var total = 100,
  hatched = 100;


window.onload = function() {
 /* Fill Rectangle*/
 ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
 ctx.fillRect(0,0,c.width,c.height);
  var id = setInterval(dec,700);
}

function inc () {
 hatched = 100;
}

function dec () {
 hatched -= 4;
 /* Perc (or percentage) takes the answer from hatched/total... */
 var perc = hatched / total;
 /* ... and filled takes perc and multiplies it by canvas.width (700px in this case) */
 var filled = perc * c.width;
 
 ctx.clearRect(0,0,c.width,c.height);

 /* Fill Rectangle*/
 ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
 ctx.fillRect(0,0,filled,c.height);

 if (hatched <= 0) {
  hatched = 0;
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Progress bar example</title>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Use Canvas to draw bar. -->
<canvas id="canvas" width="1920px" height="5px" style="border: 2px solid black">
 <p>Your computer doesn't support the canvas tag</p>
</canvas><br>
<br>

<!-- Buttons to increase and decrease values -->
<button type="button" onclick="inc();">Fill Up</button>

<script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Hopefully this helps. I think using requestAnimationFrame would actually be much more useful.